# Display only 5 li (list items) at one time using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to display 5 list items(li) using jquery. On load it should show only first 5, and then on clicking next button, it should show next 5 list items and the previous 5 list items should be hidden. But, however, its not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myList li:lt(5)').show();
    var size_li = $("#myList li").size();
    alert(size_li);
    var x = 5;
    $('#next').click(function(){      
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
        $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();        
    });
    $('#prev').click(function(){

    });

});
```

My JS fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/518/

Any thoughts where I'm going wrong?

Comment: shouldn't you hide the `LI` elements that have an index smaller than the current `x` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $lis = $("#myList li").hide();
    $lis.slice(0, 5).show();
    var size_li = $lis.length;
    var x = 5,
        start = 0;
    $('#next').click(function () {
        if (start + x < size_li) {
            $lis.slice(start, start + x).hide();
            start += x;
            $lis.slice(start, start + x).show();
        }
    });
    $('#prev').click(function () {
        if (start - x >= 0) {
            $lis.slice(start, start + x).hide();
            start -= x;
            $lis.slice(start, start + x).show();
        }
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EMD9P/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/534/)

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $children = $("#myList").children("li"),
        offset = 0,
        display = 5;

    redraw();

    function redraw() {
        $("#myList li").removeClass("hidden");
        $.each($children, function(k, v) {
            if (k < offset || k >= offset + display) $(this).addClass("hidden");            
        });
    }

    $('#next').click(function(){      
        offset += display;
        if (offset > $children.length) offset = $children.length;
        redraw();
    });
    $('#prev').click(function(){
        offset -= display;
        if (offset < 0) offset = 0;
        redraw();
    });    

});
```

**CSS:**

```
.hidden {   
 color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#next, #prev').click(function () {
    var w = this.id === 'prev' ? 'first' : 'last'
      , $m = $li.filter(':visible')[w]()[this.id + 'All'](":lt(" + x + ")");

    if ( $m.length ) {
       $li.hide();
       $m.show();
    }      
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/479Fr/

Comment: @martynas Thank you very much, it doesn't seem to be easy to maintain though :)

Answer (score 0):

A more generic way to solve your problem:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/533/

```
var minPage = 1;
var maxPage = -1;
var currentPage = 1;
var pageSize = 5;

function showCurrentPage() {
    var rangeFrom = (currentPage - 1) * 5;
    var rangeTo = (currentPage) * 5;
    var $liList = $('#myList li').hide();

    $liList.slice(rangeFrom, rangeTo).show();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    maxPage = parseInt($('#myList li').length / pageSize) + 1;

    showCurrentPage();

    $('#next').click(function () {
        if (currentPage < maxPage) {
            currentPage++;
            showCurrentPage();
        }
    });

    $('#prev').click(function () {
        if (currentPage > minPage) {
            currentPage--;
            showCurrentPage();
        }
    });
});
```