# How to filter elements on click in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is the code I have so far:

```
$(".prod-page").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
         $(".cat-item").filter(function(index) {
         // something goes here I guess?
         });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="cat-item"></div>
    <div class="cat-item"></div>
<div class="cat-item"></div>
    (more here)
</div>
```

Dynamically adding the page buttons depending on number of items (12 per page):

```
numItems = $('.cat-item').length;
numPages = numItems / 12;
lastPage = numItems % 12;

for (i = 0; i <= numPages; i++) {
$('#page-counter').append('<div class="prod-page"></div>' );
}

if (lastPage >= 1) {
$('#page-counter').append('<div class="prod-page"></div>' );
}

$(".prod-page").each(function(i) {
$(this).text(++i);
});
```

.cat-item has a display: none set in css and there are multiple buttons with the class .prod-page.

When clicking on .prod-page button, I would like to .show first 12 elements, then the next 12 elements with the class .cat-item (undefined number of times).

Any idea how to approach this? The best would be modifying the code I've already written.

Comment: Can you post your html code please?

Comment: I've updated my question, check the code above.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516428/display-only-5-li-list-items-at-one-time-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this -

when you generate the page buttons add some sort of page id

```
for (i = 0; i <= numPages; i++) {
    $('#page-counter').append('<div class="prod-page" data-pageid="'+i+'"></div>' );
}
```

then the click handler will know which page to show:

```
$(".prod-page").click(function() {
    var $button = $(this);
    var page_id = $button.data('pageid');
    var $items = $(".cat-item");
    for (var i=0; i< $items.length; i++) {
       if (i < page_id * 12 ||  i >= (page_id+1)*12 ) {
          $($items[i]).hide();
       }
       else {
          $($items[i]).show();
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: When briefly looking at your solution, it seems to be the closest to what I need, but it doesn't work to the full yet for me. It seems to generate the right divs the first time you click a button, but then nothing changes when clicking another one. 

I added the page ID both to the first .append and to the second one, do you think that might be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Sorry! My mistake, it does work in fact, thnx! I'm accepting your answer. The only problem is that it shows 13 items instead of 12, what should I modify to make it 12?

Comment: oops, just change the  `i > (page_id+1)*12`   to  `i >= (page_id+1)*12`,  will fix in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be the way you want to do..

http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/f6cPa/

```
$('li').filter(function( index ) {
    return index > 10;
  }).addClass('.cat-item');
```